How to call a number from a multi-dimensional complex list
I'm trying to make a sophisticated quiz that involves a list for a question and an answer that is included in a list. I want to call numbers from this multi-dimensional list using a "for" loop using values.
The values:
items = [[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[10, 9], [8, 7], [6, 5]]]

This is what I tried:
for a, b, c in items:
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)

The results:
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
[10, 9]
[8, 7]
[6, 5]

What I expected:
Something like this:
[[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[10, 9], [8, 7], [6, 5]]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[1, 2]

How do I get the values straightforward like this?

print(items), print(items[0]), print(items[0][0])?

"something like" is a bit vague. Is that your expected output or is it merely like your expected output?

Why should the output be like that? What's the logic?

You can manually get the values from the list like so:
items
items[value]
items[value][value]
items[value][value][value]


This is very helpful

try this one simple solution with recursion 
def zer(arr):
    print(arr)
    return None if type(arr[0]) is not list else zer(arr[0])
zer(items)

##output
[[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[10, 9], [8, 7], [6, 5]]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[1, 2]


This is very simple! thanks!

Use while loop instead
items = [[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[10, 9], [8, 7], [6, 5]]]

# Make items as an element of list and declare it as x 
x = [items]

while True:

    # break the loop if x[0] is integer
    if isinstance(x[0], int): break
    
    print(x[0])
    x = x[0] # Now x[0] becomes x
    

Output :
[[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[10, 9], [8, 7], [6, 5]]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[1, 2]

This method follows a structure and conditional automation rather calling the values directly.
